# There is an implementation restriction on ActivityHistories

Tags: apex, query, activity, activityhistory, sortorder

I have a query that I wanted to add additional sorting to the nested query ActivityHistories. The sorting works with `ORDER BY ActivityDate DESC, LastModifiedDate DESC` but when I add a third condition `ORDER BY ActivityDate DESC, LastModifiedDate DESC, CreatedDate DESC` I get a permission error stating:

> "There is an implementation restriction on ActivityHistories. When you
> query this relationship, security evaluation is implemented for users
> who don't have administrator permissions, and you must use a specific
> sort order: ActivityDate DESC, LastModifiedDate DESC"

I understand from these posts that is has to do with admin permissions:

https://community.skuid.com/t/salesforce-implementation-restriction-on-activityhistories/4939

https://documentation.conga.com/grid/latest/activity-history-and-open-activities-implementation-restriction-143886917.html

The solution suggests that I have to give my users "View All Data" permissions which I do not want to do.

Is there a way around this limitation without having to give view all data permissions to people we do not want to have this access?

Here is the query we want:

```
SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT WhoId, WhatId, Subject, Status, Response_Channel__c, Reason__c, RPC__c, Priority, OwnerId, Owner.Name, Location, IsTask, IsClosed, Id, DurationInMinutes, Description, CallType, CallObject, CallDurationInSeconds, CallDisposition, ActivityType, ActivityDate,CreatedDate, LastModifiedDate, AccountId,Date_Activity_Logged__c FROM ActivityHistories ORDER BY ActivityDate DESC, LastModifiedDate DESC, CreatedDate DESC limit 50), (SELECT n.Title, n.ParentId, n.OwnerId,  n.Owner.Name, n.Id, n.CreatedById, n.CreatedDate, n.Body, LastModifiedDate FROM Notes n ORDER BY n.LastModifiedDate DESC limit 50),(SELECT a.ParentId, a.OwnerId, a.Owner.Name, a.Name, a.Id, a.Description, a.ContentType, a.CreatedDate, a.CreatedById, LastModifiedDate FROM Attachments a ORDER BY a.LastModifiedDate DESC limit 50) FROM Lead WHERE Id =: leadId ];
```

Comment: Can you create a custom TEXT formula field on `Activity` that is the concatenation of the three datetime fields (concatenated as 3 ISO datetimes)? Then order by the custom formula field.

Comment: @cropredy I am not sure I am following. How would I create a concat Text formula field with DateTimes? I attached a picture of what I was thinking but the syntax obviously doesn't pass. And then further, once the datetimes are concatenated, how would the ORDER BY in the query be able to filter by a string of three different datetimes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a formula field on Activity called `Sortable_Activity_LastMod_CreatedDate__c`

```
TEXT(UNIXTIMESTAMP(ActivityDate)) &'-'& 
TEXT(UNIXTIMESTAMP(LastModifiedDate))&'-'&
TEXT(UNIXTIMESTAMP(CreatedDate))
```

This will generate a string that will look like

```
1632441600-1632522839-1632522839
1632441600-1632530526-1632530526
...
```

that you can sort.

Notes -- Assumes `ActivityDate` has a value, if not, the formula will generate

```
-1635469551-1635469551
```

You may want to change the formula to use `...BLANKVALUE(ActivityDate,DATEVALUE(someVal))`

where someVal is either a constant date in the past or deep future, depending on your business use case

Comment: How does this take into consideration DESC?

Comment: it is a string that can be sorted DESC, it will sort ActivityDate DESC, if any dups, then will sort LastModifiedDate DESC, if dups then finally sort CreatedDate DESC

Comment: This makes sense and I just tried running it and it works, thank you. I am curious about how the ORDER BY can look at three values separated by a dash. Is this how it is compiled with three separate values? I was under the impression that when it compiles the query runs something like "ORDER BY 1632441600 AND ORDER BY 1632522839 AND ORDER BY 1632522839". Just curious as to how it is working on the backend

Comment: no - it is ORDER BY `1632441600-1632522839-1632522839` as a single string. I used the dash merely to make the concatenated string easier to read. I could have used a colon `:` or an emoji or dispensed with it entirely

Comment: if we are setting the Sortable_Activity_LastMod_CreatedDate__c field to have a single string value (even if it is separated by dashes or colons) I don't understand how ORDER BY would be able to read each value and know how to split them out by the dash or colon. It seems like the query would order by a single value....I can ask this in a new question if this is getting too into the weeds.

Comment: Because the entire OP sort is all fields DESC, sorting on one field DESC is equivalent. If you were sorting on field 1 desc, field 2 ASC, field 3 DESC - my approach would not work

Comment: I got it now. I wasn't thinking of it that way, thank you for explaining

Comment: Updating for future readers - unfortunately I just tested again with multiple tasks records with the same activitydate and lastmodified date but different createddates and the query is still not working with the three ORDER BY parameters while signed in as a non admin user. I must have initially tested with bad data